# using crypt in php password script allows for password with extra characters?

Tags: php, encryption

ok, so I'm trying to create some password protected web pages using PHP 5.4 script and MySQL. Running a sample produced some unexpected results!

I created the password using:

```
$salt = "";
$salt.=substr("./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789",mt_rand(0,63), 1);
$salt .= substr("./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", mt_rand(0, 63), 1);
$pw1 = crypt($pw,$salt);
```

and stored the $pw1 in MySQL database.

then in my authentication pages, I retrieved the db password and used user input from a form to validate the user, checking like this:

```
get $db_pw from database then...
if (crypt($user_password,$db_pw) == $db_pw) ... proceed
```

All worked fine, but if I enter a string longer than the password it still passed thru ok.  For example: if my password was "stack", if I entered "stackoverflow" it would pass ok.  If I entered "stac" it would stop as intended.

I've tried searching on this but could not find anything similar.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://3v4l.org/BJerv cannot reproduce any problems here?

Comment: @bart: `crypt()` returns the two char salt as the first two chars of the crypted pw. passing that crypted string back to crypt() extracts the 2 char salt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the crypt function has this little caveat:

> The standard DES-based crypt() returns the salt as the first two characters of the output. It also only uses the first eight characters of str, so longer strings that start with the same eight characters will generate the same result (when the same salt is used).

So I presume that what happens does not happen on "stack" and "stackoverflow" but does with e.g. "stackove" and "stackoverflow".

Using `crypt()` is a really bad idea. Use PBKDF2 or bcrypt instead of crypt of the stone age.

Comment: Thanks!  that's what I needed... and yeah--looking at using PHPass instead.  I've heard the cautions of crypt...